# webserver using spring boot kotlin in Corda with XML

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, corda

I am developing corda application using kotlin. I am on webserver spring boot. My requirment is to recieve(postman or any API from outside) XML in requestBody and create IOU(pass) that xml as it is to Flow but i am not able to so. when i define it as a string and pass that xml i am able to do it. but for xml i am struggling. Can anyone help please. Below is my code. am doing anything wrong here. The problem is- i dont get error but it just doesnt work.

```
@PostMapping(value = ["createTransaction"],consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE],produces = [ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE])
   private  fun TransactionOne(@RequestBody ()employee:Document, @RequestParam(value = "payload") payload: String, @RequestParam(value = "partyName") partyName: String): ResponseEntity<String> {
       val partyX500Name = CordaX500Name.parse(partyName)
       val otherParty = proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(partyX500Name) ?: return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Party named $partyName cannot be found.\n")
       return try {
           val signedTx = proxy.startTrackedFlow(::IOUFlow, employee, otherParty).returnValue.getOrThrow()
           ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Transaction id {$signedTx} committed to ledger.\n")

       } catch (ex: Throwable) {
           logger.error(ex.message, ex)
           ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(ex.message!!)
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not clear what does it mean "just doesn't work". You don't have response from "startTrackedFlow"?

What do you see in logs of your nodes? I think the answer is there.

There is not enough information to help you...

Comment: The error from postman i get is "Not acceptable". I have a very plain requirement just to push xml and retrieve it.

Comment: Can you attach request response from postman? I understand that you are getting HTTP 406. What headers did you sent in request?